# Why isn't ngAnimate working on a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So, in my webapp, I have a list which consists of `<div>`'s. I want to add a nice animation to them. So I started work and added `ngAnimate` to the app.js file. I also added `ng-animate="'animate'"` to the `<div>`. I then reloaded my webapp and behold, it's not working. No animation at all. I'm using ngAnimate and AngularJS version 1.2.4

I added some of the code below:

```
<div class="col-use-list sidebar">
    <div class="col-md-12 sidebar-element" 
         ng-animate="'animate'" 
         ng-repeat="song in songs | orderBy:[filter]:reverse" 
         style="margin-bottom: 10px;"> 

        <div class="col-use-artwork" 
             style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <img alt="{{ song.name }}" 
                 src="img/artwork/{{ song.image }}.png" 
                 class="sidebar-song-image">            
        </div>

        <div class="col-use-name">      
            <p>{{ song.name }}</p>            
        </div>

        <div class="col-use-select">        
            <input type="radio" 
                   name="checkbox"  
                   ng-value="song.image" 
                   id="{{ song.image }}" 
                   class="sidebar-checkbox" />
            <label for="{{ song.image }}" class="sidebar-checkbox-label"></label>            
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div style='clear:both;height: 0;'></div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
var SongApp = angular
    .module('SongApp', 
        [
          "ui.router", 
          "ngUpload", 
          "pascalprecht.translate", 
          "ngAnimate"
        ]);
```

**css**

```
.animate-enter, 
.animate-leave { 
    -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
} 

.animate-leave.animate-leave-active,
.animate-enter {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-enter.animate-enter-active,
.animate-leave {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Try adding ng-animate after ng-repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the documentation for angular v1.2.4, the use of ng-animate service is different, now you should specify the class with animations as a normal class.

So try out this:

html:

```
<div class="col-use-list sidebar">
    <div class="col-md-12 sidebar-element animate" 
         ng-repeat="song in songs | orderBy:[filter]:reverse" 
         style="margin-bottom: 10px;"> 

        <div class="col-use-artwork" 
             style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <img alt="{{ song.name }}" 
                 src="img/artwork/{{ song.image }}.png" 
                 class="sidebar-song-image">            
        </div>

        <div class="col-use-name">      
            <p>{{ song.name }}</p>            
        </div>

        <div class="col-use-select">        
            <input type="radio" 
                   name="checkbox"  
                   ng-value="song.image" 
                   id="{{ song.image }}" 
                   class="sidebar-checkbox" />
            <label for="{{ song.image }}" class="sidebar-checkbox-label"></label>            
        </div>            
    </div>

    <div style='clear:both;height: 0;'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.animate.ng-enter, 
.animate.ng-leave { 
    -webkit-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -moz-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -ms-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    -o-transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    transition: 400ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.250, 0.750, 0.750) all;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
} 

.animate.ng-leave, animate.ng-leave-active,
.animate.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
    transform: scaleY(0);
    height: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate.ng-enter, animate.ng-enter-active,
.animate.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    -moz-transform: scaleY(1);
    -ms-transform: scaleY(1);
    -o-transform: scaleY(1);
    transform: scaleY(1);
    height: 30px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

If you see at the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ngAnimate) since v1.2 ngAnimate use is different, you have to specify a class with the animate, and put ng-enter or ng-leave on your css, the angular service would add ng-enter or ng-leave for you class in dom.